# Is a Kafka Connect worker a machine/server or just a cpu core?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#workers) Kafka Connect workers are described as processes, so in my understanding cores of cpu.

But in the same docs they are meant to provide automatic fault tolerance (in their distributed mode), so in my understanding different machines, since fault tolerance at process level is meaningless imo.

Somebody could enlighten me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Kafka Connect worker is a JVM process.

You can run multiple Kafka Connect workers in distributed mode configured as a cluster, and if one worker dies the work (tasks) are distributed amongst the remaining workers.

Typically you would deploy one Kafka Connect worker per machine. Running multiple Kafka Connect workers in distributed mode on one machine is not something that would generally make sense IMO.

I have not tested it but I don't believe that a Kafka Connect worker is tied to one CPU.

For more explanation see here: https://youtu.be/oNK3lB8Z-ZA?t=1337 (slides: https://rmoff.dev/bbuzz19-kafka-connect)